# Figure not displayed with matplotlib.use('Agg')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I work with matplotlib. When I add the following lines, the figure is not displayed.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

here is my code :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(12,9))
def convert_sin_cos(x):
    fft_axes = fig.add_subplot(331)
    y = np.cos(x)
    fft_axes.plot(x,y,'g*')
for i in range(3):
    fft_axes = fig.add_subplot(332)
    x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
    fft_axes.plot(x,i*np.sin(x),'r+')
    plot.pause(0.1)
    convert_sin_cos(x)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### That's the idea!

When I run your code, the console says:

```
matplotlibAgg.py:15: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

How can it be useful? When you're running matplotlib code in a terminal with no windowing system, for example: a cluster (running the same code with different inputs, getting lot of results and without the need to move the data I can plot whatever I need).